# Restrict block to specific pages is broken when using view pagination

Tags: views, blocks

I have a block I want displayed on a view page, which has filtering and pagination. The block shows fine when you change the filter, but if you go to page 2 (or any other page than the first), the block disappears. In the block config I have the following under "Only the listed pages":

```
myview
myview/*
```

How do I make it appear on all the pages in the view?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out since my block was itself a view, it received the `page` param from the url, and since pagination was turned on, it just went to other pages, which happened to be empty.

I fixed it by turning off pagination on the block view.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, several years later. Now that time has passed I hope you can mark this as solved.

Comment: To turn off pagination for blocks, it seems you have to set it to "Display All Items"

Answer (score 1):

use myview*

the pager will call change the URI to

```
myview?page=2 ...
```

myview* will cover that case

Comment: Actually `myview*` wasn't needed, check my own answer to see what I was doing wrong.. :)