# How to show a block on pages with url parameters?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a block that I want to show on pages matching `news` and `news?page=1`. In the 'only show on these pages' section I have `news` and `news/*` but it doesn't match the second url. Is there a way to do this?

**Update 1**: I have also tried this:

`<?php
    $url = request_uri();
    if (strpos($url, "news")) {
    return TRUE;
        }
    ?>`

But even after clearing all the caches it doesn't seem to have worked either.

I also tried the pattern `news?page=*` but that doesn't work either! Surely somebody considered being able to show blocks on paginated pages?

**Update 2**: Found the answer [Restrict block to specific pages is broken when using view pagination](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/restrict-block-to-specific-pages-is-broken-when-using-view-pagination)

Turns out the block I was trying to display was a View which was also set to display a pager (even though one doesn't appear). Turning the pager off resolved the issue.

Comment: it will not match the second as there is no `/` after `news` but an url parameter. Try `news*`

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: as indrock mentioned news* should work.

Comment: and, the next tme you use strpos() , keep in mind that how you have added i there is wrong. (strpos($url, 'news') !== FALSE)

Comment: `<?php $url = request_uri(); if (strpos($url, "news")) { return TRUE; } ?>` There are many drupal way to check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [Restrict block to specific pages is broken when using view pagination](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/restrict-block-to-specific-pages-is-broken-when-using-view-pagination)

Turns out the block I was trying to display was a View which was also set to display a pager (even though one doesn't appear). Turning the pager off resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can ajaxify the views using Ajax option in the view settings. So that page won't reload with parameters like ?page=1.

If you dont want to use ajax then you can select PHP code as visibility settings and write below php code. You need to enable php filter module to see the php code setting in the block configuration.

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == "news") {
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Have a look at here: http://drupal.org/node/1208488

Answer (score 0):

The solution as described in your own answer seems to be like a workaround for your original question, it doesn't answer the question for those case where you cannot (or do not want to) "*turn the pager off to resolve the issue*". To actually *show blocks on paginated pages* (as in your original question), you can use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module for this. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***check the path of the current page***" (so that the block is only shown on pages with a path either **matching** "`news`" or **starting with** "`news?page=`").

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)". It includes a Rules Component (in Rules export format), which you should replace by this variation of it to make it match your specific question):

```
{ "rules_show_block_on_pages_with_url_parms" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show block on pages with url parms",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "OR" : [
          { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:path" ], "value" : "news" } },
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "news?page=",
              "operation" : "starts"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

To further enhance the above Rules Component (to make it more generic), just replace the 2nd Rules Condition in it with something using an appropriate regular expression (ie to check if the current path contains a number to indicate the page id).

Answer (score 0):

To be able to configure blocks to show up or not show up based on URL parameters (same as you can for the URL path in Drupal core) use [condition query module](https://www.drupal.org/project/condition_query) for Drupal 8 or [block query](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_query) for Drupal 7.